# Java: fix malformed XML grouping tags in subgroups

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
   <hd h01="728" ... />
   <tr t01="12" ... />
   <tr t01="16" ... />
   <tl t01="9" ... />
   <hd h01="0" ... />
   <tr t01="33" ... />
   <tl t01="2" ... />
   ...
</root>
```

I need it to be like this:

```
<root>
   <record>
      <hd h01="728" ... />
      <tr t01="12" ... />
      <tr t01="16" ... />
      <tl t01="9" ... />
   </record>
   <record>
      <hd h01="0" ... />
      <tr t01="33" ... />
      <tl t01="2" ... />
   </record>
</root>
```

Every "record" will have one `<hd>`, one or more `<tr>`, and one `<tl>`, in this exactly order.

I want to `unmarshal` it with the following model classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class RootXml {

  @XmlElement(name = "record")
  private RecordXml record;
```

.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
public class RecordXml {

  @XmlElement(name="hd")
  private HdXml hd;

  @XmlElement(name="tr")
  private List<TrXml> tr;

  @XmlElement(name="tl")
  private TlXml tl;
```

But for it I have to group every "record" in a `<record>` tag.

How can I do this in Java?

First I thought about a hard-coding solution like this:

```
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("<hd", "<record><hd");
```

But then I got stuck on how to insert the close tag of record, once it should be placed after the `<tl>` tag that have a lot of attributes like `<tl t01="2" t02="234" ... />`.

I think maybe the best solution would be using a `Document` object of the XML.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Any ideas would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="hd">
   <record>
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
   </record>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
<xsl:template>
```

Don't try writing this in Java unless you have plenty of time on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the XML with a hard-coding solution:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("<hd", "</record><record><hd");
xml = xml.replaceAll("</root>", "</record></root>");
xml = xml.replaceFirst("</record>", "");
```

It's definitely not pretty, but I couldn't find a better solution.